# Unity 3D does not show anything in the hierarchy window

Tags: unity3d-gui

I am new at Unity. I saved my Unity project after one day, I did some work on it and then save again after some time I reopen it then unity does not show game objects in the hierarchy view.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are in the correct scene. If you have saved your scene correctly you can open it by going to 'File -> Open Scene' or by looking for it in the Assets folder inside the editor.